# How are posts ordered in the backend view?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, posts

I created a function that retrieves all parent posts of a post and i'm ordering by post_date.

```
select * from {$wpdb->posts} where post_type = 'page' and post_status = 'publish' and post_parent = " . ($parent == 0 ? $page_id : $parent) . ' order by post_date asc
```

I the WP backend the posts are ordered differently and it's not by publish date nor by ID.

Any idea how i can order my query so that i will have the same order as in the backend?

Thanks,
Radu

Comment: I'd recommend adding an id or date.  It's hard to ensure the exact same order unless there's an order by clause.

Comment: There is a 'order by post_date'. I also tried with ID. Asc and Desc, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this article here are six ways to customize the sort order of posts in WordPress.

[6 Ways to Customize WordPress Post Order](http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/01/22/6-ways-to-customize-wordpress-post-order/)

Also must see this link :

http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/1009

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Teez, but i don't want to change the order. I just want to write a query that will give me the posts in the exact order they are in the backend list.